# HTML - I upload new image to site, old image still loads

Tags: html, upload

I am running a linux script that downloads a picture from my website every hour, but when I change the image (by uploading a new one with the same name), such as www.mywebsite.com/images/myimage.jpg , the old copy keeps getting downloaded.  Is there a certain amount of time it takes?  I use MyDomain.com as my hosting website and use their FileManager to upload a new picture (but it overwrites the old one keeping the same name).

Any tips on how to handle this?  Even in a web browser (opposed to my linux wget command) the old picture is still there after uploading, even using clean browsers with private browsing so I don't think it has to do with browser cache.

Thanks for taking the time to read this and thanks for any help!

Comment: Is this a cache issue?

Comment: I don't think so unless IE, firefox, and chrome all use the same cache storage, and I was under the impression that private browsing doesn't use any pre-existing cache.  I changed the picture 45 minutes ago and on another computer (never accessed the site before) I still have the old image.  Maybe MyDomain.com is just having a slow time right now? I've only been at it for 3 hours.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can try to clear browsers cache or open you page in other browser to see if it works.

Second, you can add some fake values after '?' sign in image scr url:

```
<img src="path-to-your-imge/sameName.jgp?anyValueHere123" alt="" >
```

Chnge it every time when new image with same name is loaded an in this case browser will not use cache to show that image
or you can open it in incognito window.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  However, the image isn't displayed on my site.  It's meant to be downloaded via a script and displayed (digital picture frame) where I control the current picture by whatever is uploaded under the exact URL of www.mywebsite.com/images/myimage.jpg.

So the linux command wget shouldn't have anything to do with cache (please correct me if I'm wrong), but even using my phone browsers (for the first time to access the site) the old picture is still showing although I uploaded the new one >45 minutes ago.  Could it be my domain manager (mydomain.com) is just slow right now?

Comment: ok, are you shure your script works? does the time of new file is different after uploading?

Comment: The time is different. Last night I tried different computers for > 2 hours after uploading a new image. If I went to the link on any PC, it was the old one, but if I downloaded through my sites file manager, it was the new one, and the time stamp is new. Any ideas? Thanks for the response.

Answer (score -1):

the best way to upload image is between < fugure >< /figure >
and the most important tag is < img > in which your image goes

```
<figure><img src="image_name.jpg"></figure>
```

Comment: I appreciate the reply.  I contacted my domain hosting service and they actually sent me this reply:

"Hello,

Thank you for contacting us.

"We have disabled the server from caching files in .htaccess file. Now, your website will display the changes immediately."