# Image still being loaded from cache despite being updated

Tags: php, image, caching, upload, reload

I am uploading a replacement image to a server using PHP file upload.  It has the same name as the old image.

After the upload, the old image is still displayed from the browser cache but can, of course, be refreshed with Control+F5 on most browsers - then the new image is displayed.

I want to automatically get the new image to be displayed, without involving the users (they keep forgetting to refresh).  This question has been asked and answered several times, for example at [HTML - I upload new image to site, old image still loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20028324/html-i-upload-new-image-to-site-old-image-still-loads)

The solution I tried was, after the file is uploaded, then I add "fake" data to the image src attribute thus: 
    src="img.jpg?t=x" (where x is the time generated with php).

This works in the sense that in the file upload program I see the new image.  It is said to cause the image to be loaded from the server, and not the cache. I'm not sure I understand the mechanism.

I had assumed this would also force the copy of this image to be refreshed in the cache, but the next time the image is loaded, either in the same script or a different page, in the same browser, the old image still shows.  In other words the old image is still in the cache and is still being used.  Of course you can refresh and then all is well.

I have tested this on several browsers including Chrome and Firefox.

Is there a way to force the new image to be loaded not just when I add the "fake" parameter, but also to be replaced in the cache.  I'm sure this must be answered somewhere, but I can't find something that works.

Comment: src="img.jpg?t=x" try this mechanism as you exactly know how to do it, be confident and try, it will work.

Comment: src="img.jpg?noCache=<?= time()?>". By pasting a timestamp behind it you force the browser to download the image

Comment: Yes - the method above does work - the image is downloaded rather than served from the cache. But it appears it does not replace the one in the cache so this continues to be used in a different or the same page.  Is there a way to force the cache to update without a browser reload (Ctrl + F5) or clearing the cache?.